# Show picture on specific Android device triggered from web page

Tags: android, server, wifi

I want to set up multiple Android devices (maximum 50) in 1 room and one by one I want to show a picture on the different devices. My idea is to use WIFI to control them from a web page. I will connect them to a power source.

The pictures can be stored on the phones so from a web page I only need some trigger like 'show pictureX.jpeg on phone X in full screen'. And after some time the page needs to trigger 'show pictureY.jpeg on phone Y in full screen'. Etc.

But I have no idea on how to achieve this. How to connect to specific phones and how to trigger the 'show picture' part?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ask the real question. Thanks. I edited the question.